# Getting a specific array field length in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array, variable-length

I Want to get a specific field length from a Multidimensional Array but I don't know how and all I could find was sizeof(array) or count(array,count_recursive)

in javascript we can do this like :

```
var modalInfo = {
                        name : 'imagePreviewModal',
                        title : 'show picture',
                        wh : [500, 400],
                        tabs : [['imagePreviewTab', body]],
                        buttons : [],
            cancelButton : false
        };
window.alert(modalInfo.tabs.length);
```

body in : `tabs : [['imagePreviewTab',body]],` is and array.

what i need is the last line, i can get the length of modalInfo array field tabs. 
how can I do the same in php?

Comment: `var_dump` the array/object from php in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$count = count($modalInfo->tabs);
```